# collect() slowing the process down, is there any alternative?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

This is my code:

```
def fun(df, file):
    symbol = df.select(df.SMBL).distinct().collect()

    for i in symbol: 
        csv_data = df.filter(df.SMBL == i.SMBL)
        csv_data.write.csv('%s/'%(BUCKET_PATH))
```

using `collect()` slows the process. How to access the column 'SMBL' without using collect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand you are trying to write to files that are named based on the SMBL dataframe column. I suggest to write the dataframe with `partitionBy()` in which you specify the column. It might be needed to make a `user defined function` based on the SMBL column in order to get the right partition naming.

Doing this you don't need to call collect previously to the write action.